# EF Core and complex type serialization

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

Question about EF Core.

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public VeryComplexType MyVeryComplexType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what I would like to obtain is to write to the database table:

- string
- int
- string containing the json serialization of the VeryComplexType object.

Is it possible to do?

Thank you!

Comment: You could add the ignore attribute to that property and add another property that does the serialization/deserialization for the json.

Comment: Whats the issue, just make a dto